# MTP with Android phone unreliable on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, android, mtp

With 12.04, I was able to connect my Android phone without problem (using MTP) to my Ubuntu machine. Open Nautilus, there is my phone, and I can click through to the folders that I wanted.

However, ever since 14.04, it has been extremely unreliable. Open Nautilus, and sometimes (about a third of the time) my phone is there. When it isn't there, the only solution is to reboot Ubuntu. When it's there, clicking though to the phone's folders sometimes works, and sometimes results in an error. Even when it works, the phone will often disappear without warning halfway through browsing the folders.

I have installed mtpfs; I have also followed the [how-to in the forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226702). I also tried replacing my USB cord in case it was faulty. No luck.

What can I do to diagnose and ultimately fix this, please?

**EDIT:**

The idVendor is `18d1` and the idProduct is `4ee1`.

The default entry in `/lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules` reads:

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4ee1", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", MODE="660", GROUP="audio", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"
```

The entry in `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` reads:

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4ee1", MODE=”0666"
```

The entry in `/lib/udev/rules.d/69-mtp.rules` reads:

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4ee1", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"
```

Comment: I've had similar problems in Xubuntu. My quick fix was to install gmtp and work through that.

Comment: @DracNoc I've installed gMTP. Unfortunately, it hangs when I press Connect. :(

Comment: I noticed that same problem when I tried gmtp for the first time, but after that it worked fine.

Comment: I don't understand why do this problem do not receive more attention as it is a serious usability issue for Ubuntu. This was the only bug report I could find...

    https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1314556

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a machine when I 'upgraded' the distribution from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS.  There were a lot of other issues with the 'upgrade', so I just reformatted and installed 14.04 on the empty drive to solve ALL my problems.  The upgrade seemed like it worked, but the more I used it, the more it was obvious that there were a ton of little things that were broken that made the system frustrating to use.  (wacky java and other lib problems.... HW-stuff broken or unreliable like this, etc...)

Try booting from a 'live USB' version of 14.04 and see if that fixes this problem, if it does, you may have other issues and it'd be easiest to backup what you need and re-install to fix all of it at once.

Comment: Thanks, but my 14.04 was a clean installation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `MTP` works fine in Trusty. You can try this:

1. *Uncomment* `#user_allow_other` in `/etc/fuse.conf`.
2. Run `lsusb` and see your device's vendor ID. It will be something like `1d6b:0002`.
3. Add the following line to `/lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules`.

   `ATTR{idVendor}=="1d6b", ATTR{idProduct}=="0002", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"`
4. Add the following line to `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`.

   `ATTR{idVendor}=="1d6b", ATTR{idProduct}=="0002", MODE=”0666"`
5. `sudo service udev restart`
6. `sudo reboot`

*Replace the Vendor and Device IDs of course*.

Like I said, `MTP` should work out of the box, but the above manually adds relevant entries to your devices list.

Comment: As explained in my post, I have already done this, with the exception of `/lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules` — because that file already contains the entry. However, that entry also has the phrases `MODE="660"` and `GROUP="audio"`. Would that make a difference? Should I remove them? Why would the connection sometimes work and other times not?

Comment: I have edited my original question to give further information.